# React Native chagne image source on button click

Tags: react-native, touchablehighlight

Hi I am trying to change image on a button click but cant seem to get the image  to change. Here is my code.

```
constructor(){
   super()
   this.state = {
      autologin_active: true
   }
}

toggleAutoLogin(){
   this.state.autologin_active = this.state.autologin_active ? false : true;
}


<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.toggleAutoLogin()} style={styles.registerButton} underlayColor='#99d9f4'>
  <View style={styles.detailBoxTick}>
    <Image style={styles.imageTickStyle} source={this.state.autologin_active ? Images.rememberTickImg : Images.rememberUnTickImg} />
    <Text style={styles.tickBoxText}>
      Auto Login
    </Text>
  </View>          
</TouchableHighlight>
```

can some one please help. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Have checked with alert that the state is changing on click. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you correctly, in `toggleAutoLogin()`, you are updating your state with `this.state.autologin_active = .....` which is updating the state but preventing the re-render so that you can't see the image changing.

You need to update the state with setState({}) in order to re-render the component (Image).

Your code for `toggleAutoLogin()` would be:

`this.setState({ autologin_active: this.state.autologin_active ? false : true})`

Comment: Thank you for that. cant believe i didnt check that. thanks again :)

Comment: Happens. Good Luck.